# how to show pdf file in ext.window?

Tags: pdf, extjs

It doesn't work, what is wrong?

```
var win = new Ext.Window({
    title: 'PDF Content',
    width: 400,
    height: 600,
    maximizable: true,
    layout: 'fit',
    plain: true,

    items: { // Let's put an empty grid in just to illustrate fit layout
        xtype: 'component',
        autoEl: {
            tag: "iframe",
            src: "../../../resources/august2013.pdf"
        }
    }
    //items : [ {
    //    html: '<object width="100%" height="100%" data="../../../resources/august2013.pdf"></object>'
    //} ]
})
win.show();
```

This view I am getting after inserting code below from `Deamon`!

[image]

Comment: Don't edit the question with respect to the answers from the users. Leave it intact like how was it before.

Comment: i want to show Daemon and other user an Image! any ideas how can i do it in comments?

Comment: @RagimsRagimovs At least mark your additions appropriately, e.g. by a preceding **EDIT:** or something similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :

```
var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window' {
    title: 'PDF Content',
    width: 400,
    height: 600,
    modal: true,
    closeAction: 'hide',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'component',
        html: '<iframe src="../../../resources/august2013.pdf" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>',
    }]
});
win.show();
```

Comment: see above what iam getting after using your code, any idea why PDF is still not displayed??

Comment: Its working for me @Ragims.I think the problem might be with your pdf.Are you getting any error?

Comment: can I in this window show also image to test it? the i need just to change html : '<iframe src="../../../resources/test.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>', like this or?

Comment: You mean to say,you want to test it by displaying image.Yes, you can test i,it works.Please verify the url.You should have your image or pdf or whatever in your war.