# Ext.ux.panel.PDF with Ext JS 3.4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1, extjs3, pdf.js

I've planned to use https://github.com/SunboX/ext_ux_pdf_panel to view PDF files in my project.

But the version I'm using 3.4.
can this version do the stuff?

I have got an error in ext-all.js

```
  Uncaught TypeError: b[(d.xtype || e)] is not a                             
  functionExt.ComponentMgr.create @ ext-all.js:7
```

Comment: `A PDF Viewer Panel for ExtJS 4.1`. It makes clear that you cant use it in 3.4

Comment: thx for responding, if there is no way to do downgrade is there a similar extension

Comment: Unfortunatly there is no such advanced plugin for 3.4. But something you could do is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379290/how-to-show-pdf-file-in-ext-window

Comment: when using Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {  it returns the same error  as shown. Uncaught TypeError: b[(d.xtype || e)] is not a                             
  function Ext.ComponentMgr.create @ ext-all.js:7

Comment: it worked when i have replaced Ext.create with new Ext.Window({. thx a lot